# Automeme poster (like dank memer) in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make something like Dank Memer's automeme in discord.py as a cog for [Red,](https://discord.red) a self-hosted open source discord bot. I have some pretty simple code to fetch the memes:

```py
    async def memes(self, ctx):
        """Get the dankest memes Reddit has to offer. Soon, you'll be able to specify by subreddit and number of memes"""
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                response = await response.json()
            embedColor = await ctx.embed_colour()
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title= response['title'],
                url = response['postLink'],
                color = embedColor,
            )
            embed.set_image(url=response['url'])
            embed.set_footer(text=f"r/{response['subreddit']} | Requested by {ctx.author.name} | Enjoy your dank memes!")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I was thinking I could store the channel id to post the memes in and the delay for memes in a dict, which I can do in like 5 min. However, I don't know how to wait a certain amount of time and then post a meme in a specified channel.

The docs for Red are [here](https://docs.discord.red), if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can get a channel like so:

`channel = bot.get_channel(id) # id is an int representing a channel's ID`

To send your embed to that channel:

`await channel.send(embed=embed)`

To wait for a specified time:

`await asyncio.sleep(secs) # secs is an int representing the number of seconds to wait for`

In your case, you could definitely use a dict pairing channel ids with their corresponding wait time:

```py
myDict = {7473839655739: 5} # channel id: wait time in seconds
channelID = ctx.channel.id
await asyncio.wait(myDict[channelID]) # waits for 5 seconds
```

Comment: I need to to that with multiple servers though, and without hard-coding it. I was going to link the delay to wait for with the channel id in a dict, but I don't know how to automatically send it in multiple servers with a different delay

Comment: Sorry I need some clarification. You want to send memes to several guilds on a loop, but want to have different frequencies at which the memes are sent for each guild?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what i want to do

Comment: Storing the time to wait for in a dict for each channel sounds fine. You could then use `ctx.channel.id` to retrieve the wait time from that dict for the current channel.

Comment: Would that work if multiple channels were set? Also, if it would, how could I make it so it repeats?

Comment: Yes this would work if the duct had multiple channel ids linked to wait times. You can put the whole thing in a while loop, and use `bot.loop.create_task(memes())` to make it a background task.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and tested it!
I am sure it will work!

```
async def memes(self, ctx):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"

    async with session.get(url) as response:

      response = await response.json()

      embed = discord.Embed(
        title= response['title'],
        url = response['postLink'],
        color = 0x5865F2,
      )

      embed.set_image(url=response['url'])

      embed.set_footer(text=f"r/{response['subreddit']} | Requested by {ctx.author.name} | Enjoy your dank memes!")

      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```